# Excluding mentions when counting words in a database of tweets

Tags: python, api, twitter

I need to count the total number of words in a csv file which is my database of tweets.
How do I exclude mentions (all the characters starting with @) from counting?

Here's what I have for now:

```
words = open('file_directory', 'r').read()
words = words.replace('.',' ').replace('!',' ').replace('?',' ').replace(';',' ').lower()
words = words.split()
print(words)
print("For the query 'lala' we have %s" %len(words))
```

I'm new to Python, so your help would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: To filter a sequence using a test function there is "filter". To test for the start of a string there is the "startswith" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension

```
new_words = [i for i in words if i[0] != '@']

print("For the query 'lala' we have %s" %len(new_words))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using regex to remove word starting with `@`:

```
words = re.sub(r'@\w ', '', words)
```

The documentation for `re.sub` can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) as well as the python regex [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret your question right, you want to filter out any words that have `@` as their first character? Here's how you can do it with a list comprehension:

```py
# [...]
words = words.split()
words = [word for word in words if not word.startswith("@")]
# [...]
```